# How can I show that each infinite set contains a countably infinite subset?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Could anyone help me solve the below problem?

> Use the axiom of choice and the generalized principle of recursive definition to show that each infinite set $X$ contains a countably infinite sebest? (H.L Royden, Real Anaysis, 3rd edition, 1988)

Also, can one prove it without using the axiom of choice or the principle of recursive definition?

Thank you!

Comment: There are models of ZF set theory in which the result is false, but the full axiom of choice is not needed. For instance, the [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) is sufficient (and that article should help you prove the result). You might be interested in the article on [Dedekind infinite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Comparison_with_the_usual_definition_of_infinite_set) as well.

Comment: @Brian I appreciate it. I'll need some time to digest the material you suggest. I'll get back once I've done some study. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! $\,$

Comment: There are probably *a lot* of other questions on this. Please search the site before posting in the future.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Got it. Thx for your guidance! I'm a novice in this area, so this kind of advice is definitely helpful!

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to completely avoid AC, but it is possible to use a weaken version of it:

Let $X$ be infinite, then let $[X]^{<\omega}$ be the set of finite subsets of $X$.

Define the partition, $P$, of $[X]^{<\omega}$ by the equivalence relation of $|\cdot |=|\cdot |$, that is:

> For all $n∈\Bbb N$, $A_n=\{x∈[X]^{<\omega}\mid |x|=n\}$
>
> $P=\{A_i\}_{i∈\Bbb N}$

Now by the [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) we can find a sequence $B_n$ such that for each $n$, we have $B_n\in A_{2^n}$, that it: $|B_n|=\boldsymbol{2^n}$.

Define the sequence $C_0=B_0$, $C_n=B_n\setminus\bigcup_{i<n}B_i$, because $|B_n|>\sum_{i<n}|B_i|$, $C_n$ is never empty, also notice that for each $m≠k$ we must have $C_m∩C_k=\emptyset$.

Again, by the axiom of countable choice, we can find a sequence $a_n$ such that for each $n∈\Bbb N$, we have $a_n∈C_n$, the set $\{a_i\}_{i∈\Bbb N}$ is countable infinity subset of $X$.

Comment: Awesome answer! thx!

Comment: The below answer seems to be much simpler. Do you think there's any flaw in it?

Comment: @SungheeYun it is not wrong per se, but it doesn't explain where exactly you use the axiom of choice. The bellow answer uses *dependent choice* which is stronger than *countable choice*, and because you asked about how to avoid choice, it is better to use the weakest choice principal possible

Answer (score 1):

Let S be an infinite set

$S\ne \emptyset \Rightarrow \exists x_1 \in S$

Because S is not finite,

$\Rightarrow\exists x_2 \in S - \{x_1\}$

$\Rightarrow\exists x_3 \in S - \{x_1, x_2\}$

...

$\Rightarrow\exists x_{n+1} \in S - \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$

A function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow S$

$f(\mathbb{N}) = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, ...\}$

$\Rightarrow f$ is one-to-one and onto

$\Rightarrow f(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq S$ and is countable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understand you answer. I'm not sure of this since I'm not an expert, but why do you think many others say we need some kind of axioms, e.g., axiom of choice, to prove this? Do you think there's any possibility for your answer missing something?